# How can I use React hooks to respond to a prop change before render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to use a functional component and React hooks to implement a simplified auto-scroller that will automatically scroll a container to the bottom when the child content overflows. But the auto-scrolling should only happen when the scrollbar is already enar the bottom (e.g., if the user has scrolled up to look at output, the scroll position should not change when new content comes in).

I know how to implement the auto-scrolling behavior by using refs and performing computation on clientHeight, scrollTop, and scrollHeight.

The problem I have is that I need to compute a `shouldAutoScroll()` check BEFORE the component is re-rendered.

My flow needs to look like this:

```
<container>
   {props.children}
</container>

When props.children changes:
   1. Check if the scrollbar is near the bottom and store the result
   2. Update container to reflect the new props.children
   3. If the check from step 1 is true, scroll to the bottom
```

I can't seem to find a way to to this using `useEffect` and/or `useLayoutEffec`. When using these what happens is:

```
   1. Scroll position is at bottom
   2. props.children updates with new items
   3. <container> is rerendered, pushing the scrollbar up
   4. The checkScrollBarBottom() method is called and returns false
   5. The scrollbar is not auto-scrolled
```

I need to keep the component generic, so that it can auto scroll regardless of what type of component or element props.children is. In some cases the change to props.chldren might be a single line. In others, it might be 20 lines, or it might be an image.

If I were using an older-style class component, I could do the computation in *componentWillReceiveProps()*. How do I replicate this with hooks?

Comment: Can you reproduce it in https://codesandbox.io ?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered one solution that works, but seems a little messy.

The solution is to calculate and update `shouldAutoScroll()` during the container's `onScroll()` event. This seems messy because I am capturing a ton of useless intermediate scroll information, when all I care about is the scroll position at the moment the update starts (but before the component is re-rendered).

Full code:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useLayoutEffect } from 'react';
import styles from './AutoScroller.module.scss';

export function AutoScroller({children, className=''}) {
  const classNames = `${styles.default} ${className}`;

  const containerRef = useRef(null);
  const shouldAutoScroll = useRef(false);

  function updateShouldAutoScroll(element, tolerance) {
    const {scrollHeight, scrollTop, clientHeight} = element;
    const result = scrollHeight - scrollTop <= clientHeight + tolerance;

    shouldAutoScroll.current = result;
  }

  function onContainerScroll(e) {
    updateShouldAutoScroll(e.target, 25)
  }

  useEffect(function autoScroll() {
    if (shouldAutoScroll.current) {
      const element = containerRef.current;
      element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
    }
  });

  return (
    <div className={classNames} ref={containerRef} onScroll={onContainerScroll}>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}
```